# Run SPIED with predefined patterns

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I need to create patterns file from a corpus A and run SPIED on corpus B using extracted patterns from corpus A. I can do it by Basilisk. How can I do it by SPIED? I believe SPIED is much better than Basilisk so I need to do it. Would you please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

SPIED does not support it right now.. I would probably be able to get this in the code in 1-3 weeks. I will update this thread then.